# calling Azure functions from Slack getting error : The 'token' parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value

Tags: command, token, slash, slack, azure-functions

Tried to setup a custom command slack integration.  Looks to be very easy from this post:  http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-slack-bots/

However whenever I trigger the custom command.  I get this error message

The 'token' parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value

Also from my Azure functions logging I know my functions endpoint does not get called.

Any ideas what Slack is complaining about?

Comment: Maybe share some details? Like what programming language you're using, your code so far, what logging you're looking at, where you're seeing that error message, etc.

Comment: Try setting the WebHook setting to "Not a WebHook" and see if it still fails.